# RapidJSON: How to move one Document to another?

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I'm trying to pass a Document as a parameter (in this case to a C++ Class C'tor, but doens't really matter), and move it, so the orig Document will become Null, and the class member will hold the document.

Example:

```
class A
{
    rapidjson::Document m_payload;

    A(rapidjson::Document& payload)
    {
        m_payload = payload; // DOESN'T WORK ('operator =' is a private member of 'rapidjson::GenericDocument<...>')
    }
};
```

I know that if it would have been a Value, the operator= would have worked, but can't get it to work with Document.

Workarounds I found so far:

1. m_payload.Swap(payload); // This works specifically here, but not what I wanted.
2. m_payload = std::move(payload); // I prefer not to use C++11 operations.

Obviously I prefer to move and not copy considering performance.

Comment: moving is a C++11-only concept, so it doesn't really make sense to say that you "prefer not to use C++11 operations"

Comment: Rapidjson works by "Move Semantics" when doing value assignments, it's really not related to C++11. What I'm trying to do is to apply those move semantics when working with Document also.